# Javascript - Change/convert image data url to file url in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, url, uri

Is possible to change or convert the data url of image to file url ?

For example, I got image from the link but the data was very long such as

data:image/x-icon;base64,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

So How can convert it to be such as

file:///storage/emulated/..../image1.jpg

Comment: Is the `data URI` at Question the complete?

Comment: open the url in a new tab, then menu > save file as.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the MIME type of a valid `data URI` with `"application/octet-stream"`, set value at `.href` of `<a>` element, set `download` attribute value to `"image1.validExtension"`, append element to `document.body`, call `.click()` on `a` element

```
var stream = validDataURI.replace(/[^:][\w/-]+(?=;|,)/, "application/octet-stream");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = stream;
a.download = "image1.validExtension";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```